# OIDC integration with google cloud identity platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I could not use our own OpenID provider with google cloud platform to authenticate user to Firebase authentication framework, it complains invalid discovery document.
Although I ran test on https://openid.net/certification/testing/ it passes all test for discovery endpoint. Attaching snippet here.
Also my OIDC discovery endpoint : https://hagext.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/https/api/rest/v3.0/oauth/smartiddigitalaccess/.well-known/openid-configuration
Any help would be really appreciated! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAGiI.png)
[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message you have provided, it would be best to review the documentation on OpenID Connect with Google Identity Platform/GCP:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect

Otherwise, it would be best to reach out to the GSuite support team as Identity Platform is under G Suite, and products such as Google’s SAML and OpenID Connect support can be used with G Suite support. You may follow this link to reach out to GSuite support:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?pli=1